# dropdown controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In my webpage I have two dropdown controls for namely ddlmonth and ddldays ( for month & days)
I write a  method for current month in ddlmonth and current day in ddldays and i call that method in page load event it working fien but when i select (in ddlmonth ) different month and different day and insert into database the values inserted in database is current month and current day, actually i select different month and day

This is my code

This is the method for current date display in ddlmonth dropdwon control and ddlday

```
public void getMonth()
{
    ddlmonth.SelectedIndex = DateTime.Now.Month -1;
    ddldate.SelectedIndex = DateTime.Now.Day - 1;
}
```

I call this in page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getMonth();
}
```

If I call the getMonth method in postback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!ispostback)
    {
        getMonth();
    }
}
```

it not displaying the current month and date

without postback it is working

When I select different month and day and insert into database it is taking current month and day

Please help me

Comment: wonder what happened when, in January you go that that page ... there is no Month 0 :) - same with the day part ;)

Comment: The getMonth method set the values for the DropDownList controls, how do you get the values FROM the controls?

Comment: Can you post the code for taking the value of drop downs and passing it to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Request.Form["ddlmonth"] and Request.Form["ddlday"] to retrieve the values.

Comment: it is not working mr.astander please try if u not understand my problem i will send again

Comment: we need to see the code from where you try to access the values and insert to the db

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood, but to "call the getMonth method in postback", you need check for ispostback = true, not false.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(isPostback)
    {
        getMonth();
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the case whenever a postback occurs the value in the drop down boxes will be set to the current month and day.

Comment: isn't that what he wants?  Anyways, I give up.  Bad question.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should use

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!ispostback)
    {
        getMonth();
    }
}
```

The page is loaded and dropdowns showing Current date and month.
After that you choose different date and month and click some button to save that in database.
In the button event you write the insertion code and if required then there again call getMonth() method to load again the current date and month in the dropdowns. The date u chose in the dropdowns will be saved in DB. If required you call getMonth() method to load current date again as below.

```
  protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //-------- insertion code ----------------//
              getMonth();
        }
```