# working with dropdown controls

Tags: asp.net

i have dropdown controls in my application namely ddlmonth and ddlday respectively and i added months(january,february ect in ddlmonth) and days added to ddldays(1,2,.....31) when i run my page i display current month and date this is my code

```
 public void getMonth() {
        ddlmonth.SelectedIndex = DateTime.Now.Month -1;
        ddldate.SelectedIndex = DateTime.Now.Day - 1;
    }
```

and i place this in page load even. like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
         getMonth();
     }
```

it is working fine, but when i keep getMonth() in ispostback it is not displaying current month and day.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       if(!isPostback) {
         getMonth();
         }
    }
```

present i place without ispostback in pageload when i select ddlmonth (dropdown) diffent month and ddlday(dropdwon) diffent day (not current month and day) when i press button 
in database it is inserting current month and day, actually i select diffent month and day
and this is my code.

```
  protected void btnEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
                clsevents.Month = ddlmonth.SelectedValue.ToString();
                clsevents.Day = ddldate.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
```

but in database it is inserting current mont and day when i select diffent mont and day in ddlmont(dropdwon) and ddlday
please help me some one.

Comment: why you posted same question instead of update exising one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438395/dropdown-controls-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my complete example code, first is the code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            getMonth();
        }
    }

    private void getMonth()
    {
        ddlDay.Text = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
        ddlMonth.Text = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
    }

    protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string strDate = ddlDay.Text + "/" + ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Value + "/09";
       getMonth();
    }
```

And here is my html.

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDay" runat="server" CssClass="inputfield">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="3"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="4"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="5"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="6"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="7"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="8"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="9"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="10"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="11"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="12"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="13"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="14"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="15"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="16"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="17"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="18"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="19"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="20"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="21"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="22"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="23"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="24"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="25"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="26"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="27"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="28"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="29"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="30"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="31"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="January"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="February "></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="March"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="April"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="May"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="June"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="July"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="August"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="September"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="October"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="11" Text="November"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="12" Text="December"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnClick" Text="Click" runat="server" CssClass="Button" OnClick="btnClick_Click" />
```

Sorry I have not pasted the whole html.
Hope you will get your solution , as I have tested above code.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the code. Please try the code below and check.

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("val");

            DataRow dr;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[0] = i;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            ddlDay.DataTextField = "val";
            ddlDay.DataValueField = "val";
            ddlDay.DataSource = dt;
            ddlDay.DataBind();
             getMonth();
        }
    }
    public void getMonth()
    {
        ddlMonth.SelectedIndex = DateTime.Now.Month - 1;
        ddlDay.SelectedIndex = DateTime.Now.Day - 1;
    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSelectedDate.Text = ddlDay.SelectedValue + " / " + ddlMonth.SelectedValue + " / 09";
    }

}
```

**Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            day :
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDay" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            Month:
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Jan" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Feb"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Mar"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Apr"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="May"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Jun"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="Jul"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="Aug"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="Sep"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="Oct"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="11" Text="Nov"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="12" Text="Dec"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
             <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
             <hr />
            <asp:Label ID="lblSelectedDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the scenario you have mention in above code what I have understand is that you want to save the user selected date in the database and then reset the current value to the month and the day???
You have to use the IsPostBack property as if you don't use it and don't place your getDate function under the IsPostBack function then it will reset the user selected value to the current month and day if you look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

link you can see that the life cycle of the web page is to

1. Load
2. Validation
3. Postback event handling

Here I have mention Important event handler, You can see that Load event which is the page load is fired every time page post backed. Now if page is post back by any of the control like button in your case then the IsPostBack is true and here you code in the Page load is not executed if you place it in the IsPostBack check. Now if you want to reset the value of the day and month control then you can call your function after submitting to the database.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Asim saija you understand my problem but if i place in ispostback current month and day  not displaying curent month and day. if i place without postback it is working. when i select different month and day it is inserting current month and day not which i selected.